# SQL: look up value in a different table if a given condition is met

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two SQL tables with related data and I need to do a conditional lookup where I mostly look up values in the main table, but if a certain condition in the main table is met, I go to the second table in addition.

The tables look like this (apologies for unsightly formatting):

> MAIN

| subscription_id | status | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Active | 2020-1-1 | 2022-12-1 |
| 2 | Canceled | 2020-1-1 | 2022-12-1 |

> HISTORY

| subscription_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Active | 2020-1-1 |
| 2 | Active | 2020-1-1 |
| 2 | Canceled | 2021-4-1 |

I want to look up which subscriptions were active on a given date.
The MAIN table gives the start and end dates of subscriptions and their current status. However, if a subscription was canceled, it doesn't show the actual cancelation date, only the original end date. The HISTORY table shows all changes in subscription status, including cancelations. For example, subscription 2 was created on 2020-1-1, was originally going to expire on 2022-12-1, but was canceled on 2021-4-1.

So what I need to do is select all subscriptions from MAIN whose start and end dates contain the date I'm interested in, but if the subscription status is Canceled, I need to look it up in HISTORY and only select it if the date in its "Canceled" row is later than the date I'm interested in.

I'm trying to do this with a UNION statement, first selecting just the active subscriptions from MAIN, then selecting canceled ones based on their cancelation date in HISTORY. For example if the date of interest is 2022-1-1:

```
(SELECT subscription_id from Main
WHERE status = 'Active' AND start <= '2022-1-1' AND end >= '2022-1-1')
UNION
(SELECT m.subscription_id from Main m
JOIN
(SELECT * from History
WHERE status = 'Canceled' AND date > '2022-1-1') h
ON m.subscription_id = h.subscription_id
WHERE m.status = 'Canceled' AND start <= '2022-1-1' AND end >= '2022-1-1')
```

This runs, but I'm inexperienced with SQL and am not certain it does what I want -- does the logic seem sound?

Alternatively, based on Jonas Metzler's suggestion in comments, I've come up with a different approach, which basically tries to re-create the Main table but take the end date from History if the subscription was canceled:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM history WHERE status='Canceled') 
SELECT m.subscription_id, m.status, start,
(CASE WHEN m.status='Canceled' THEN cte.date else m.end) as end
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN cte ON m.subscription_id = cte.subscription_id
```

I can then use this new table to look up specific dates. Again, I'm not totally sure this does what I'm intending, so it would be great to get a sanity check.

Comment: which darabase are you using and what have you tried so far

Comment: @nbk I've given the table structures above. Like I said, I'm not even sure where to begin with this.

Comment: please tag the database which you are using

Comment: @nbk I don't understand what you're asking -- the database consists of those two tables.

Comment: then please read the tag description https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info

Comment: You will need to use JOIN and CASE WHEN for that. I advice to read the documentations and try to find the correct query on your own, this will help much more than pasting an answer from here. See here for JOIN: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins and here for CASE WHEN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks. Is it possible to do it with a UNION statement as in the code I've added? I'm having trouble figuring out how to use CASE here.

Comment: @nbk I've added the snowflake-sql tag as I'm querying Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case of subscription business model, which has life cycle status like `Active`, `Canceled`, `Expired`...etc. And, it's supposed to have a renewal process updating the expiration date in `MAIN.end` column.  All status changes should be captured in `HISTORY` table (Usually it's related to legal requirements). With that in mind,

```
set @some_date = '2020-03-01';

with cte_subscription as (
select subscription_id,
       status,
       date  as start_date,
       lead(date,1) over (partition by subscription_id order by date) as end_date
  from history)
select *
  from cte_subscription
 where @some_date >= start_date
   and @some_date <= COALESCE(end_date, '9999/12/31');
```

Outcome:

```
subscription_id|status|start_date|end_date  |
---------------+------+----------+----------+
              1|Active|2020-01-01|          |
              2|Active|2020-01-01|2020-04-01|
```

Let us change the date to:

```
set @some_date = '2020-05-01';
```

Outcome:

```
subscription_id|status  |start_date|end_date|
---------------+--------+----------+--------+
              1|Active  |2020-01-01|        |
              2|Canceled|2020-04-01|        |
```

By the way, if it's beyond a subscription's expiration date, the `HISTORY` table should look like:

```
subscription_id|status  |date      |
---------------+--------+----------+
              1|Active  |2020-01-01| <-- Subscription started
              2|Active  |2020-01-01|
              2|Canceled|2020-04-01| <-- Subscription cancelled
              1|Expired |2022-12-01| <-- Subscription expired
```